# What is the Control Panel URL?

Tags: control-panel

The installation instructions say: "A few seconds later, you should have a working Craft install!
 ... If it was successful, Craft will redirect your browser to the Control Panel." My installation route was Terminal, and all I have at the end is "*** installed Craft successfully (time: 53.862s)". So, please help me to find the URL where I can start learning to use this design facility. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The default URL to access Craft is `/admin`.

Note also this can be changed to anything you like using the `cpTrigger` [config variable](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#cptrigger).

Comment: Sorry if this is a repeat of my first comment. It is lost on my screen. I was saying that I used https://craftcms.com/admin and takes me to a 404 page. Can you give a full URL?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your local development environment. You need a web server with a host and domain.

For instance, using MAMP Pro, I would set up a host for say, local.mytestsite.dev and have it serve files from the @web directory within the Craft 3 installation.

Then you would use `local.mytestsite.dev/admin` to get to the control panel.

But this is all dependant on how you have set up your system.

Comment: I will follow the route you outline, foamcow. So, thanks.

Comment: You might also want to check out https://craftquest.io/courses/craft-cms-3-tutorials, which is free and 4.5 hours of video on how to get up and running with Craft.

Answer (score 1):

For those using a Mac, who are not prof. developers, and who used Terminal to get successful installation, I provide the following steps, which have worked for me.

1. After you get the message which says that installation was successful, search for a folder named “craftcms” inside the folder that has your own User files, within the “Users” folder.  For example, on my Mac, the “craftcms” is inside “lestone2” folder, where we have ‘Macintosh HD>Users>lestone2’ as the pathway.  I would advise you to place a copy of this valuable folder in off-line storage somewhere.
2. Head over to the folder named “htdocs”, whose pathway is ‘Macintosh HD>Applications>MAMP>htdocs’.  Move a copy of the “craftcms” folder inside htdocs. (It is a good idea to confirm that you have moved all the hidden files in the process.)
3. Go to your browser and enter what will be your analog of “http://localhost:8888/craftcms/web/admin/dashboard" , and you will land right at the Control Panel. (N.B. All this assumes you have already adopted MAMP and have used it to set up a database with at least one test table at MySQL, you have instructed MAMP to “turn on servers” and the port for  the turned-on Apache is some number like the 8888 you see above.

Good luck!